# How to run a thread until a condition becomes true in c#

Tags: c#

I am writing a program to send SMS every 5 minutes. I want to stop this when the system time is 6 PM. How can I do that? This is my current code.
 I want to modify this according to my above requirement.

```
while (true)
{        
        sms.SendSMS();

        Thread.Sleep(30000);


}}).Start();
}
```

Comment: Use the correct tags; C is different to C#

Comment: I don't even understand how to format this code. Please add some more code.

Comment: Clarification needed: how can the system date be "6PM"?

Comment: Hint: Use timer, `Thread.Sleep` is a bad idea.

Comment: `while(time < 6pm)` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the below condition to check system TIME.

```
      `if(DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("HH") == "18") //Hour is in 24hour format`
```

Comment: Thnx a lot.. I'll try this..Really appreciate u'r support.. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Generally never use Sleep is bad idea , use timer instead:

```
System.Timers.Timer SendSMS = new System.Timers.Timer();        
SendSMS.Interval = 300000;  ///300000ms=5min    
SendSMS.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(SendSMS_Elapsed);
SendSMS.Enabled=true;

 void SendSMS_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            sms.SendSMS();
        }
```

Add a second timer to check the time and stop when is 6pm:

```
 System.Timers.Timer StopSendSMS = new System.Timers.Timer();        
    StopSendSMS.Interval = 100;      
    StopSendSMS.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler( StopSendSMS_Elapsed);
    StopSendSMS.Enabled=true;


 void StopSendSMS_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                  if (int(DateTime.Now.Hour)==18))
                   {
                     SendSMS.Enabled=false;
                     StopSendSMS.Enabled=false; ///no need to check anymore
                   }

            }
```

Comment: When I add this code program just ruuns.. nothing happens.. can anyone say the reason for it? System.Timers.Timer SendSMS = new System.Timers.Timer();        
SendSMS.Interval = 300000;  ///300000ms=5min    
SendSMS.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(SendSMS_Elapsed);
SendSMS.Enabled=true;

 void SendSMS_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            sms.SendSMS();
        }